# Calculate $I= \iiint\limits_{\Omega}2\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y\,{\rm d}z$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, alternative-proof, volume, multiple-integral, jacobian

> Calculate
> $$I= \iiint\limits_{\Omega}2\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y\,{\rm d}z$$
> with
> $$\Omega: \left\{\begin{matrix}
> \left ( \frac{x}{3} \right )^{2}+ \left ( \frac{y}{2} \right )^{2}+ z^{2} & \leq & 1\\ 
> z & \geq & 0
> \end{matrix}\right.$$

My solution is:

Let $u= x/3, v= y/2, w=z.$ Using Jacobi's formula with:
$$\left | J \right |= \begin{vmatrix}
{x_{u}}' & {x_{v}}' & {x_{w}}'\\ 
{y_{u}}' & {y_{v}}' & {y_{w}}'\\ 
{z_{u}}' & {z_{v}}' & {z_{w}}'
\end{vmatrix}= \begin{vmatrix}
3 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 2 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1
\end{vmatrix}= 6\Rightarrow I= \iiint\limits_{\Omega}2\cdot 6{\rm d}u{\rm d}v{\rm d}w= 12\cdot \frac{1}{2}V= 6\frac{4\pi r^{3}}{3}= 8\pi$$

But seems like this way's not useful if I replace $x^{2}/9$ by $x.$ So I want to see another way to solve this problem without Jacobi's formula. Maybe I can understand when we should use Jacobi's formula. I used these to prep for my test. I need to the help, thank you.

Comment: I think you've hit the nail right on the head: the transformation gives a much nicer integral and avoids a lot of unnecessarily complicated integration. I wouldn't change a thing about your solution, but to be fair I am also a Jacobian junkie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $\Omega$ is half of the ellipsoid $E$ with semiaxes $3$, $2$, $1$. It follows that
$$\int_\Omega 2\>{\rm dvol}={\rm vol}(E)=3\cdot2\cdot1\cdot{4\pi\over3}=8\pi\ .$$